# Do implicitly acquired locks also last until the end of a transaction?

Tags: postgresql

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO q VALUES(1);
    SELECT * FROM q;
END;
```

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html I would assume that the `INSERT` query acquires a lock of type `ROW EXCLUSIVE`. Does this mean that this lock is also active when the `SELECT` query is run? I'm assuming this based on: "Once acquired, a lock is normally held till end of transaction." (quote from the above documentation)

In general, is the above semantically the same as:

```
BEGIN
    LOCK q IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    INSERT INTO q VALUES(1);
    SELECT * FROM q;
END;
```

?

Comment: You could test this yourself, using a second database connection

Comment: Simply yet great idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea of Frank_Heikens I tested the above assumptions and can confirm that the implicitly acquired lock of the `INSERT` query stays active until the end of the transaction.